# Leer por consola CSharp

Tags: c#

Estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación y acabo de resolver el siguiente ejercicio.

```
Ingresar un número y mostrar la suma de los números que lo anteceden.
Al ingresar el 5 me da como resultado el 10
```

.

Como hago para que por consola al ingresar por ejemplo el `5`, me muestre `1+2+3+4 = 10`, dejo el código que realice.

```
int num, suma = 0;

Console.Write("Ingresa un número:");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)

   suma = suma + i;

   Console.Write("La suma de los números que anteceden a el número: " + num + " es " + suma + ".");
   Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacer con un ciclo for, concatenando en cada vuelta el valor que lleva el ciclo, el programa quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
        Console.Write("Ingresa un número: ");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int suma = 1;

        Console.Write("La suma de los números anteriores a " + num + " es: 1");
        for (int i = 2; i < num; i++)
        {
            suma += i; //Para poder mostrar los números desde el uno, ya que i en un inicio va a valer 0
            Console.Write(" + " + i);
        }
        Console.Write(" = " + suma);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

La variable `suma` se inicializa en 1 por los siguientes motivos:

1) Ya sabemos que antes de cualquier número siempre va a estar el número uno, entonces es por demás que lo pongamos en el ciclo for más adelante.

2) Para poder concatenar los signos "+" en cada vuelta, estos tienen que escribirse al inicio de cada `Console.Write()` dentro del ciclo for, por lo que es necesario tener un número ya escrito antes. Me explico: Antes de iniciar el ciclo for se escribe la frase "La suma de los números anteriores a " + num + " es: 1" ya que, al tener ese uno ahí, podemos concatenar, dentro del for, al inicio de cada escritura un signo más, ya que sabemos que antes siempre va a haber un número. Esto nos sirve para que, al final de las vueltas del ciclo for no aparezca un signo más. Si dejamos el signo más al final de la escritura del ciclo for, quedaría de esta manera (en el caso de que num = 5): `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + = 10`

Espero te sirve, cualquier duda estamos para servir.

Comment: Lo entendí perfectamente gracias.

Comment: De nada, ya sabes

Answer (score 2):

Prueba almacenado todos los valores en una variable con su simbolo y al final la imprimes como desees... asi:

```
int num, suma = 0;
string result="";

Console.Write("Ingresa un número:");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){

   suma = suma + i;
    if (i==0) {
        result = result + i;
    }else{
        result= result + "+" +i;
    }

   Console.Write("La suma de los números que anteceden a el número: " + num + " es " + suma + ".");
   Console.ReadKey();
}

Console.Write("La suma de los números que anteceden a el número: " + result + " = " + suma + ".");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Espero te sirva y la marques, ReNiceCode...

Answer (score 1):

Hola cambia tu código por este:

```
int num, suma = 0;

Console.Write("Ingresa un número:");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < = num; i++) // añade el = en la condición 
    suma = suma + i;

Console.Write("La suma de los números que anteceden a el número: " + num + " es " + suma + ".");
Console.ReadKey();
```